# How to compare timestamp fields in HQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I have a Java.Util.Timestamp column in a table and I´m unable to do a comparison with a variable in WHERE clause. With this code:

```
        // Using Calendar to convert Java Date 'horarioEliminar' to Sql Timestamp 't'
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(horarioEliminar);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        Timestamp t = new java.sql.Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());

        String horQ = "FROM Academia.Horarios WHERE horario ="+ t;
        horario = (Horarios) session.createQuery(horQ).uniqueResult();
```

I got an Exception:

> ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-873] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.reportError line 1:57: unexpected token: 10

But I checked that System.out.println(t) result matches with a value stored in horario column. How can I properly compare these two timestamps?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the timestamp as a query parameter like this:

```
 Timestamp t = new java.sql.Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());

 String horQ = "FROM Academia.Horarios WHERE horario = :ts";
 horario = (Horarios) session.createQuery(horQ).setParameter("ts", t).uniqueResult();
```